How to Measure the Frequency Response of a Circuit with Current Feedback Using Bode 100?
I want to use the Bode 100 Vector Network Analyzer to measure the frequency response of my circuit. I understand that with voltage feedback, a typical injection transformer can be used at the feedback loop.

I'm working with a circuit that uses current feedback rather than voltage feedback. The current is sensed through a current transformer, and the feedback is processed by a microcontroller.

However, I'm unsure how to properly inject a signal and measure the response for a current feedback system.
Specific questions:
1.Where should the injection signal be applied in a current feedback loop?
2.How should the Bode 100's channels be configured to measure the loop gain?

No, you can't do that, the signals must be dc in and dc out, ac-modulated around a bias point. If you post a more comprehensive schematic diagram, we may comment in a more appropriate way. What do you want to implement, a constant-current regulation loop? Cos' I've never seen a current transformer placed as you've drawn.

The CT makes no sense.  It's either open, or shorted by the diode.  There's no way to get a measure of the current from it.

I'm not aware of measuring current gain for this sort of exercise. This article by Analog Devices may give some pointers on what you're trying to accomplish.

Yes, I'm implementing a constant-current regulation loop. As you can see, I've placed the current transformer (CT) on the secondary side of the transformer in the LLC converter. After the CT, I’ve used a diode and a low-pass filter to process the signal, and it’s then fed into the ADC of the microcontroller. @VerbalKint

Yes, you're right. Apologies for the confusion; I’ve corrected the diagram @JohnD

any opninion or comment ???? @VerbalKint

I would not use a CT but either a simple shunt resistance or a Hall-effect sensor (or a TMR type also) either placed in the hi-side or low-side dc path, not pulsating. Check my free templates, there is a CC-CV buck converter which runs on the free demo Elements.
